# Creating rectangle within a blob using OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Input Image:

[image]

Output Image:

[image]

I have several colored blobs in an image and I'm trying to create rectangles (or squares--which seems to be much easier) inside the largest blob of each color. I've found [the answer to how to create a rectangle that bounds a single largest blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746473/opencv-find-bounding-box-of-largest-blob-in-binary-image), but am unsure as to how to find a square that simply fits inside a blob. It doesn't have to be the largest, it just has to be larger than a certain area otherwise I just won't include it. I've also seen some work done on polygons, but nothing for amorphous shapes.

Comment: If you provide a non compressed image, I'll post into my answer also the results on your image.

Answer (score 2):

For a single blob, the problem can be formulated as: [find the largest rectangle containing only zeros in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478447/find-largest-rectangle-containing-only-zeros-in-an-n%C3%97n-binary-matrix).

To find the largest axes-oriented rectangle inside a blob, you can refer to the function `findMinRect` in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32682512/5008845). The code is a porting in C++ of the original in Python from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418912/5008845).

---

Then the second problem is to find all blobs with the same color. This is a little tricky because your image is jpeg, and compression creates a lot artificial colors near to borders. So I created a png image (shown below), just to show that the algorithm works. It's up to you to provide an image without compression artifacts.

Then you just need to create a mask for each color, find connected components for each blob in this mask, and compute the minimum rectangle for each blob.

Initial image:

[image]

Here I show the rects found for each blob, divided by color. You can then take only the rectangles you need, either the maximum rectangle for each color, or the rectangle for the largest blob for each color.

Result:

[image]

Here the code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418912/5008845
Rect findMinRect(const Mat1b& src)
{
    Mat1f W(src.rows, src.cols, float(0));
    Mat1f H(src.rows, src.cols, float(0));

    Rect maxRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float maxArea = 0.f;

    for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (src(r, c) == 0)
            {
                H(r, c) = 1.f + ((r>0) ? H(r - 1, c) : 0);
                W(r, c) = 1.f + ((c>0) ? W(r, c - 1) : 0);
            }

            float minw = W(r, c);
            for (int h = 0; h < H(r, c); ++h)
            {
                minw = min(minw, W(r - h, c));
                float area = (h + 1) * minw;
                if (area > maxArea)
                {
                    maxArea = area;
                    maxRect = Rect(Point(c - minw + 1, r - h), Point(c + 1, r + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return maxRect;
}


struct lessVec3b
{
    bool operator()(const Vec3b& lhs, const Vec3b& rhs) {
        return (lhs[0] != rhs[0]) ? (lhs[0] < rhs[0]) : ((lhs[1] != rhs[1]) ? (lhs[1] < rhs[1]) : (lhs[2] < rhs[2]));
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Find unique colors
    set<Vec3b, lessVec3b> s(img.begin(), img.end());

    // Divide planes of original image
    vector<Mat1b> planes;
    split(img, planes);
    for (auto color : s)
    {
        // Create a mask with only pixels of the given color
        Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(255));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            mask &= (planes[i] == color[i]);
        }

        // Find blobs
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        findContours(mask, contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
        {
            // Create a mask for each single blob
            Mat1b maskSingleContour(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));
            drawContours(maskSingleContour, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

            // Find minimum rect for each blob
            Rect box = findMinRect(~maskSingleContour);

            // Draw rect
            Scalar rectColor(color[1], color[2], color[0]);
            rectangle(img, box, rectColor, 2);
        }
    }

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28155-inscribed-rectangle) to locate the largest square or rectangle inscribed inside arbitrary shape. Although it's MATLAB instead of C++/OpenCV, you can easily change its source code to fit to your needs.

For locating the largest rectangle inscribed inside convex polygons, check out [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) (with code).