# How to merge bounding boxes with groupRectangle?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with bounding boxes like so:

[image]

I want to merge overlapping bounding boxes.

I tried: `cv::groupRectangles(detected, 1, 0.8)`

My expectation was that I get a single box for each cluster.

But I got this:

[image]

As you can see, **the problem is, there is no box for the dartboard in the middle and for the right one**.

How do I resolve this? I would preferably like to use the OpenCV api rather than coding my own merging algorithm.

I see that it eliminates regions bounded by exactly one box. I want it to not  do that.

I have tried tweaking the parameters randomly but I've gotten much worse results. I would love some guidance in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

## How to define overlapping rectangles?

We need a way to define when two rectangles overlap. We can use the `&` intersection operator to find the intersection of the two rectangles, and check that it's not empty:

```
bool overlap(const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs) {
    return (lhs & rhs).area() > 0;
}
```

If we want to ignore small intersections, we can use a threshold over the intersection area:

```
bool overlap(const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs, int th) {
    return (lhs & rhs).area() > th;
}
```

But now the threshold depends on the dimensions of the rectangles. We can use the [*"Intersection over Union"*](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/07/intersection-over-union-iou-for-object-detection/) metric (IoU) which is in the range [0, 1], and apply a threshold in that interval.

```
bool overlap(const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs, double th) {
    double i = static_cast<double>((lhs & rhs).area());
    double u = static_cast<double>((lhs | rhs).area());
    double iou = i / u;
    return iou > th;
}
```

This works well in general, but may show unexpected results if the two rectangles have a very different size. Another approach could be to check if the first rectangle intersects with the second one for most of its area, and vice versa:

```
bool overlap(const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs, double th) {
    double i = static_cast<double>((lhs & rhs).area());
    double ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(lhs.area());
    double ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(rhs.area());
    return (ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area > th) || (ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area > th);        
}
```

Ok, now we have a few ways to define when two rectangles overlap. Pick one.

## How to find overlapping rectangles?

We can cluster the rectangles with [`cv::partition`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga2037c989e69b499c1aa271419f3a9b34) with a predicate that puts overlapping rectangles in the same cluster. This will put in the same cluster even two rectangles that do not directly overlap each other, but are *linked* by one or more overlapping rectangles. The output of this function is a vector of cluster, where each cluster consists in a vector of rectangles:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>> cluster_rects(const std::vector<cv::Rect>& rects, const double th)
{
    std::vector<int> labels;
    int n_labels = cv::partition(rects, labels, [th](const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs) {
        double i = static_cast<double>((lhs & rhs).area());
        double ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(lhs.area());
        double ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(rhs.area());
        return (ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area > th) || (ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area > th);
    });

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>> clusters(n_labels);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i) {
        clusters[labels[i]].push_back(rects[i]);
    }

    return clusters;
}
```

For example, from the rectangles in this image:

[image]

we obtain these clusters (with a threshold of `0.2`). Note that:

1. in the top left cluster the three rectangles do not overlap with each other
2. the rectangle on the top right is on its own cluster, because it doesn't intersect enough with the other rectangles.

[image]

## How to find a rectangle that represents a cluster?

Well, that's really application dependent. It can be the union of all rectangles:

```
cv::Rect union_of_rects(const std::vector<cv::Rect>& cluster)
{
    cv::Rect one;
    if (!cluster.empty())
    {
        one = cluster[0];
        for (const auto& r : cluster) { one |= r; }
    }
    return one;
}
```

[image]

Or it can be the maximum inscribed rectangle (code below):

[image]

Or something else. For example, if you have a *score* associated with each rectangle (e.g. it's a detection with a confidence) you can sort each cluster by score and take only the first one. This is a an example of non-maxima-suppression (NMA) and you keep only the highest score rectangle for each cluster (Not showed in this answer).

Pick one.

Below the working code I used for creating these images. Please play with it :)

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

std::vector<cv::Rect> create_some_rects()
{
    std::vector<cv::Rect> rects
    {
    {20, 20, 20, 40},
    {30, 40, 40, 40},
    {50, 46, 30, 40},
    {100, 120, 30, 40},
    {110, 130, 36, 20},
    {104, 124, 50, 30},
    {200, 80, 40, 50},
    {220, 90, 50, 30},
    {240, 84, 30, 70},
    {260, 60, 20, 30},
    };
    return rects;
}

void draw_rects(cv::Mat3b& img, const std::vector<cv::Rect>& rects)
{
    for (const auto& r : rects) {
        cv::Scalar random_color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
        cv::rectangle(img, r, random_color);
    }
}

void draw_rects(cv::Mat3b& img, const std::vector<cv::Rect>& rects, const cv::Scalar& color)
{
    for (const auto& r : rects) {
        cv::rectangle(img, r, color);
    }
}

void draw_clusters(cv::Mat3b& img, const std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>>& clusters)
{
    for (const auto& cluster : clusters) {
        cv::Scalar random_color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
        draw_rects(img, cluster, random_color);
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>> cluster_rects(const std::vector<cv::Rect>& rects, const double th)
{
    std::vector<int> labels;
    int n_labels = cv::partition(rects, labels, [th](const cv::Rect& lhs, const cv::Rect& rhs) {
        double i = static_cast<double>((lhs & rhs).area());
        double ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(lhs.area());
        double ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area = i / static_cast<double>(rhs.area());
        return (ratio_intersection_over_lhs_area > th) || (ratio_intersection_over_rhs_area > th);
    });

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>> clusters(n_labels);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i) {
        clusters[labels[i]].push_back(rects[i]);
    }

    return clusters;
}

cv::Rect union_of_rects(const std::vector<cv::Rect>& cluster)
{
    cv::Rect one;
    if (!cluster.empty())
    {
        one = cluster[0];
        for (const auto& r : cluster) { one |= r; }
    }
    return one;
}


// https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418912/5008845
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/34905215/5008845
cv::Rect findMaxRect(const cv::Mat1b& src)
{
    cv::Mat1f W(src.rows, src.cols, float(0));
    cv::Mat1f H(src.rows, src.cols, float(0));

    cv::Rect maxRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    float maxArea = 0.f;

    for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < src.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (src(r, c) == 0)
            {
                H(r, c) = 1.f + ((r > 0) ? H(r - 1, c) : 0);
                W(r, c) = 1.f + ((c > 0) ? W(r, c - 1) : 0);
            }

            float minw = W(r, c);
            for (int h = 0; h < H(r, c); ++h)
            {
                minw = std::min(minw, W(r - h, c));
                float area = (h + 1) * minw;
                if (area > maxArea)
                {
                    maxArea = area;
                    maxRect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(c - minw + 1, r - h), cv::Point(c + 1, r + 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return maxRect;
}

cv::Rect largest_inscribed_of_rects(const std::vector<cv::Rect>& cluster)
{
    cv::Rect roi = union_of_rects(cluster);

    cv::Mat1b mask(roi.height, roi.width, uchar(255));
    for (const auto& r : cluster) {
        cv::rectangle(mask, r - roi.tl(), cv::Scalar(0), cv::FILLED);
    }

    cv::Rect largest_rect = findMaxRect(mask);
    largest_rect += roi.tl();

    return largest_rect;
}



std::vector<cv::Rect> find_one_for_cluster(const std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>>& clusters)
{
    std::vector<cv::Rect> one_for_cluster;
    for (const auto& cluster : clusters) {
        //cv::Rect one = union_of_rects(cluster);
        cv::Rect one = largest_inscribed_of_rects(cluster);
        one_for_cluster.push_back(one);
    }
    return one_for_cluster;
}


int main()
{
    cv::Mat3b img(200, 300, cv::Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

    std::vector<cv::Rect> rects = create_some_rects();

    cv::Mat3b initial_rects_img = img.clone();
    draw_rects(initial_rects_img, rects, cv::Scalar(127, 127, 127));

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Rect>> clusters = cluster_rects(rects, 0.2);

    cv::Mat3b clustered_rects_img = initial_rects_img.clone();
    draw_clusters(clustered_rects_img, clusters);

    std::vector<cv::Rect> single_rects = find_one_for_cluster(clusters);

    cv::Mat3b single_rects_img = initial_rects_img.clone();
    draw_rects(single_rects_img, single_rects);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot fine-tune `groupRectangles()`. The second parameter for your example should be 0 though. With 1, all singular rectangles *have* to be merged somewhere.

You could first grow small rectangles and stay with a conservative threshold parameter if you want a better clustering of the small ones. Not an optimal solution though.

---

If you want to cluster based on overlap condition, I would suggest to write your own simple algorithm for that. `groupRectangles()` simply does not do that. It finds rectangles similar in size and position; it does not accumulate rectangles that form a cluster.

- You could fill a mask `cv::Mat1b mask(image.size(), uchar(0));` with the rectangles and then use `cv::connectedComponents()` to find merged regions. Note that filling is trivial, loop over all rectangles and call `mask(rect).setTo(255);`. If the overlap is not always reliable, you could use `cv::dilate()` to grow rectangles in the mask before the connected-components step.
- You could test all rectangles for overlaps and associate them accordingly. For a huge amount of rectangles, I suggest disjoint-set/union-find data structure for efficiency.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try and single out all "single" rectangles first, then apply opencv's groupRectangle on the remaining rectangles. Could you expand a bit on how one can you use union-find for this task? :)

Comment: I gave a easier-to-implement alternative in an edit to the answer.