# Opencv Simpleblobdetector example sketch throws cv::exception (-231)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I tried to run the following example sketch for the SimlpeBlobTracker:
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/BlobDetector/blob.cpp

However, when I try to run the program,

```
./track
```

it breaks and returns:

> OpenCV Error: The function/feature is not implemented () in
>   detectAndCompute, file
>   /home/sixtimesseven/Desktop/opencv/opencv/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp,
>   line 144
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>         what():  /home/sixtimesseven/Desktop/opencv/opencv/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp:144:
>   error: (-213)  in function detectAndCompute

I am compiling with a makefile:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

track : track.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o track track.cpp $(LIBS)
```

And I am running Ubuntu 16 and OpenCV 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this topic, but I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622304/opencv-3-blobdetection-the-function-feature-is-not-implemented-in-detectand), which suggests that it might be something related to how you're declaring a certain object.