# Detecting blobs on image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to get some descriptors for each white area on image to filter that areas and operate with them separately. How can I do it?

I have read [How to use OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/tutorial-on-opencv-simpleblobdetector) and http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ but still can't get any result with my simple image.

[image]

Here is my code in python

```
img = cv2.imread("map.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.blobColor = 255
params.filterByColor = True
params.minArea = 16
params.filterByArea = True
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
keypoints = detector.detect(255 - img)
len(keypoints)
# 0
```

OpenCV 3.1.0

Image is grayscaled.

UPD: Code updated following comment by @api55

Comment: you need to pass the blob params, setting the blobColor to 255 and filter by color to true. By default it tries to find dark blobs in white background. Or you could invert the colors of the image

Comment: @api55 I have updated code (in post too) but still no result

Comment: Try changing also the minArea parameter to something small, like 16 (4x4 pixel blob approx). In the tutorial, it says that filter by color is not working (not sure what version you have).... you can try inverting the image colors

Comment: @api55 Nothing changed

Comment: @Antonio The result is an empty array of keypoints. What should I show?

Comment: Check [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28573944/2436175), seems more up to date.

Comment: @Antonio I have already checked it.

Comment: @AskhatNuriddinov That's not the code you are using here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tutorial on OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/tutorial-on-opencv-simpleblobdetector)

Comment: try loading the image as greyscale, and remove the inverted color thing... `cv2.imread("map.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: @api55 I tried just to copy the code and change `imread("blob.jpg")` to `imread("map.jpg")` and add `print(len(keypoints))` and got the same result.

Comment: @api55 My image is already grayscaled (added this in post)

Comment: @AskhatNuriddinov even if your image is greyscale, OpenCV may load it as BGR... don't ask me why, but I it seems that is the default....

Comment: @Antonio The image is showed properly with `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot`. Converting it to bmp didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @api55 Sorry, haven't updated the code in the post. On my computer it was grayscaled.

Comment: Please try the (updated) code [here](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/BlobDetector/blob.py)

Comment: @Antonio No result

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get some descriptors for each white area on image to filter that areas and operate with them separately. How can I do it?

My goal could be reached with `sklearn.measure.label`. This function returns a numpy array with the same shape and labels for each connected area.

But anyway it is still not clear why SimpleBlobDetector from OpenCV doesn't work.

Comment: Try skimage blob detection. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_blob.html.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I had to remove the fiterbyarea parameter:

```
params.filterByArea = False
```