# how to find the cordinates of a shape in a image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

in a BGR image, there is a red color circle, which i have to detect and find its cordinates.

i have converted the bgr image to hsv , then using upper and lower limit of red seperated the red color from image , now how to find the cordinates of that red circle

`lower_red = np.array([0,150,50])`
`upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])`
`mask_img1 = cv2.inRange(img1_HSV,lower_red,upper_red)`
`res=cv2.bitwise_and(img_1,img_1,mask=mask_img1)`
`cv2.imshow('mask',res)`
`cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: So you have seperated the parts you are interested in into a seperate matrix ? If so could you provide the picture you currently have that only contains your red circle ?

Comment: use np.where(mask == (255,255,255))

Comment: @fmw42 it didnt work . btw thanks for ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python/OpenCV/Numpy, you can use np.where or better np.argwhere. Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image and set the bounds
img = cv2.imread("red_circle.png")

# get color bounds of red circle
lower =(0,0,255) # lower bound for each channel
upper = (0,0,255) # upper bound for each channel

# create the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# get coordinates of mask where it is white
coords = np.argwhere(mask == 255)
print(coords)

# write mask to disk
cv2.imwrite("red_circle_mask.png", mask)

# display mask
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Results:

```
[[ 95 100]
 [ 96  98]
 [ 96  99]
 [ 96 100]
 [ 96 101]
 [ 96 102]
 [ 97  97]
 [ 97  98]
 [ 97  99]
 [ 97 100]
 [ 97 101]
 [ 97 102]
 [ 97 103]
 [ 98  96]
 [ 98  97]
 [ 98  98]
 [ 98  99]
 [ 98 100]
 [ 98 101]
 [ 98 102]
 [ 98 103]
 [ 98 104]
 [ 99  96]
 [ 99  97]
 [ 99  98]
 [ 99  99]
 [ 99 100]
 [ 99 101]
 [ 99 102]
 [ 99 103]
 [ 99 104]
 [100  95]
 [100  96]
 [100  97]
 [100  98]
 [100  99]
 [100 100]
 [100 101]
 [100 102]
 [100 103]
 [100 104]
 [100 105]
 [101  96]
 [101  97]
 [101  98]
 [101  99]
 [101 100]
 [101 101]
 [101 102]
 [101 103]
 [101 104]
 [102  96]
 [102  97]
 [102  98]
 [102  99]
 [102 100]
 [102 101]
 [102 102]
 [102 103]
 [102 104]
 [103  97]
 [103  98]
 [103  99]
 [103 100]
 [103 101]
 [103 102]
 [103 103]
 [104  98]
 [104  99]
 [104 100]
 [104 101]
 [104 102]
 [105 100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use simpleblobdetector, there is a stackoverflow post on it:

[How to use OpenCV SimpleBlobDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/how-to-use-opencv-simpleblobdetector)