# Get X and Y coordinates of white dot in a black screen python

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a python library to detect the pixel's coordinate of white dots in a black background png image and return a NumPy array of its coordinates

ie.

[image: black screen white dot]

Comment: OpenCV can solve this

Comment: please review [ask]. question was tagged OpenCV by author, so the author knows about OpenCV. this question simply lacks research effort (searching for answers). perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/how-to-use-opencv-simpleblobdetector or browse the tutorials on https://docs.opencv.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find white dot by `numpy.where`. You can try this way:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('XXWck.png')

x, y, z = np.where(img==(255,255,255))
points = zip(x,y)
print(points)
```

Comment: Hello Is there any way to get the center pixel than a whole lot of pixel